# Заменить текст внутри тега

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция которая принимает первым параметром текст, а вторым в каких тегах заменять текст. В функции находит первые вхождение и все, как сделать чтобы искала все совпадения ?

```
function escapeByEl(context, conf) {
        var tagsStart = conf.tags.map((tag) => {
          return `<${tag}>`;
        });

        var tagsEnd = conf.tags.map((tag) => {
          return `</${tag}>`;
        });

        conf.tags.forEach((tag, index) => {
          var start = context.indexOf(tagsStart[index]) + tagsStart[index].length;
          var end = context.indexOf(tagsEnd[index]);

          var text = context.substring(start, end);

          console.log(text);
        });
      }

escapeByEl('<code> some text </code><code> hello </code>', { tags: ['code'] });
```

Выводит только `some text`, надо чтобы находило и `hello`

https://plnkr.co/edit/1llWSxfMmjaj7zkklKKk?p=info

Comment: Возможно, потому что вы используете `conf.tags.forEach`, а в массиве `conf.tags` всего один элемент. Получается, весь код  `var start = context.indexOf(tagsStart[index]) + tagsStart[index].length; ....` выполняется один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в данном коде поиск подстроки осуществляется один раз,  так как нет прохода по всей строке, в `conf.tags` находится только 1 объект.

Нужно добавить блок while и передавать конечный индекс предыдущего поиска:

```
conf.tags.forEach((tag, index) => {
  var start = context.indexOf(tagsStart[index]);
  while (start > -1)
  {
    start += tagsStart[index].length;
    var end = context.indexOf(tagsEnd[index], start);
    var text = context.substring(start, end);
    console.log(text);
    start = context.indexOf(tagsStart[index], end);
  }
});
```

[**Обновлённый plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GDsH5dh6Wj2cNxRfeTaJ?p=preview)